# How to get a image array from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Noobie here, Apologies if this question is silly,

I have developed a image match game with set of default images, now i want to access images from directory. the game logic is done in Javascript. I used php to get random 8 images from the directory and the code is as follows.

random.php:

```
 <?php $dire="Annotated Dataset/";
 $images = glob($dire. '*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
 shuffle($images);
   echo 'json_encode(array_slice($images,0,8))';
 ?>
```

I want to use the images in the above array in the Javascript function which has switch case. I wanted to use each image from array inside the switch case:

Game.js:

```
 function getgImage(number) {
 $.ajax({
      url: "random.php",
      type: "post",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {},
      success: function (response) {

         // You will get response from your PHP page (what you echo or print)
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });


   if(number=='1'){
   return ranarray[0];
   }
   else if(number == '2'){
   return ranarray[1];
   }

   else if(number == '3'){
   return ranarray[2];
   } 

   else if(number == '4'){
   return ranarray[3];
   }

   else if(number == '5'){
   return ranarray[4];
   }

   else if(number == '6'){
   return ranarray[5];
   }

   else if(number == '7'){
   return ranarray[6];
   }

   else if(number == '8'){
   return ranarray[7];
   }
   else {
   return '<img src="resources/logo.png">';

   }
   }
```

I tried something like in the above code, but I am not able to get the images in the switch case. Can someone help me with this problem.

I need the array of 8 images from php to be inside switch case of the javascript file, each image for each case. Kindly help me with some solution. Thank you in advance

Comment: echo 'json_encode(array_slice($images,0,8))'; remove quotation

Comment: @anikislamShojib i tried by removing the quotation, but still the output is same, I get string value, instead of images (i.e., i get alphabet e,p,h etc instead of images)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax to fetch them from PHP and use them in JavaScript.

Tip: `die(json_encode(getgImage(1));`

## imagefetcher.php

```
function getRandomImage() {

  $dire   = "Annotated Dataset/";
  $images = glob($dire. '*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $images = shuffle($images);

  return $images[rand(0, (count($images) - 1))];

}

die(json_encode(getRandomImage()));
```

## game.js

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        url: "imagefetcher.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
           // You will get response from your PHP page (what you echo or print)
           alert('Response from PHP file: ' + response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: CAn you show me how to use this ajax in my code, i never used it before. I will be helpful for me.

Comment: Simply just add it between <script> tags and link url to your php file which will provide the ajax request of the result it needs. It will output a json response (response in the success function) with the data you sent from PHP.

Comment: He said javascript, this solution is with the library Jquery. He could do the same with `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open("POST", "https://www.mywebsite.com/test.php");  
    xhr.send(); if (xhr.readyState == 4)
  if (xhr.status == 200)
    var your_array_answer = xhr.responseText; `

Comment: So i add this ajax code, and inside the function response{ echo 'json_encode(array_slice($images,0,8))'; } and later in the switch case i return $images[i].... Was I correct ? ..

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows what about the die(json_encode(getImage(1)) , where should i use this , sorry for these questions, i never used ajax code before

Comment: @Uviiii your ajax response will be whatever your php file outputs. If you use die() it will output whatever you put inbetween. Just make sure your PHP file has no other outputs apart from what you want to use in your ajax request's success function.

Comment: So don't combine PHP with JavaScript, use php in your php file and echo whatever you want to use.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows I understood the idea u suggested but i dont how to implement it, If i echo the images in the php and use ajax call in javascript file, how to get the images inside the if condition. I have updated the code, Can u please show a snippet of code how to use them inside the if conidtion